# Linking CSS button to email - How can it be done?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to link the submit button to be an email address. But can't seem to get it to work.

Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong?

It looks like it works on first inspection, but whenever I upload it to the site it doesn't work =S

Here is the HTML:

```
<a href="mailto:email@email.co"><input type="submit" value="Get In Touch" name="submit" class="submit" id="submit"></a>
```

Below is the CSS:

```
body {
font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
padding: 100px;
font-size: 13px;
}

div {
background: #fff;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 200px;
padding: 100px;
text-align: center;
/* border-radius */
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
/* box-shadow */
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
}

input[type="submit"] { 
height: 50px; 
padding: 0 48px; margin: 10px auto 0 auto; 
background: #090a0b; 
border: 0; 
text-transform: uppercase; 
font-family: "Open Sans";
font-size: 24px; 
color: #fff; 
font-weight: 400;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
transition: all 0.2s ease;
opacity: 1;
-webkit-appearance: none;
border: solid 1px #fff;
-webkit-border-radius: 1px;
-moz-border-radius: 1px;
border-radius: 1px;
background: transparent;  
}
```

Comment: Why you want to do that, only use `a` tag and apply some css

Comment: What doesn't work when you upload it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use submit button inside `<a>` than you could use this instead.without `<a>` tag.

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" class='button' value="Mail US" onclick="window.location.href='mailto:email@email.co'">
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
 }
```

**Fiddle HERE**: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xeemez/CYk7H/)

> Otherwise you could just use `<a>` tags instead and cover it with `CSS`.
>   Both are great approaches

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

html

```
<a class="button" href="mailto:email@email.co">Get In Touch</a>
```

css

```
.button {
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
 }
```

Just use `a` tag and apply some css

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `<a>` tag and style it, or a `<button>` (which is sometimes fubar in earlier IE), or, if you *need* to use a form you could do this

```
<form action="mailto:user@user.com">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Email">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to submit a form full of data to an email address, a simple `mailto` is not what you are going to need. All `mailto` does is open the native email application on your computer and fill out the "To:" field with the email address you put in the href.

To submit an email with form data you would need an email handler. In PHP you can simply attach the `$_POST` data to the php `mail()` function. Here is a [good tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/) on that.

Another option would to use a hosted solution like [emailmeform](http://www.emailmeform.com/). Or even a javascript mailing solution like [addthis](http://www.addthis.com/) or [sharethis](http://www.sharethis.com/). They have APIs available to allow you to input data into the email being sent.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I was originally going to go for a form but decided to just use the mailto function.