# How to link a button to an email address

Tags: html

I have a button (styled with CSS). The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="button">Kontakt</div>
```

Now I want to link the button to an email address. The following solution did not work. It shows the email address (email@email.de) as text in the button.

```
<div class="button"><a href="mailto:email@email.de">Kontakt</a></div>
```

and the solution with the div container as the inner HTML element also does not work:

```
<a href="mailto:email@email.de"><div class="button">Kontakt</div></a>
```

Any ideas on how I can show the word "Kontakt" as Text on the Button which links to an email address?

Comment: No need for the div. Change your button CSS to also apply to `a` elements and then do  `<a class='button' ....`

Comment: `<a class="button" href="mailto:email@email.co">Kontakt</a>`
this may help you out [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626755/linking-css-button-to-email-how-can-it-be-done]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just write

```
<a class="button" href="mailto:email@email.de">Kontakt</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

when i do this i cant see the button anymore. When i look in chrome deveoper tool or firebug i see a new class <a href="mailto:email@email.de" class="spamspan">email@email.de</a>
But i dont know why... that must be a kind of Spam Protection??

Comment: Sad that we loose semantic, because it looks like a button, not a link.

Answer (score 4):

Easy solution is to wrap button with a element.

```
<a href="mailto:email@email.de">
<button class="button">Kontakt</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="mailto:email@email.co">Get In Touch</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="mailto:email@email.de" class="mail-button">Kontakt</a>
```

and add css to make the `<a>` tag like button.

Answer (score -1):

Just write this in you HTML file

```
<a href="mailto:email@email.de">Kontakt</a>
```

and for the css add the following

```
a {
    text-decoration: none; /* to hide the underline */
}
a:visited {
    /* this will style the button after clicking for example the color of the text */
    color: white; /* change it to the text color in your normal style */
}
a:hover {
    /* the style here will appear when the mouse is over the button */
    /* this will help you to make it act like a real button */
}
```

or add `onclick` to the button tag and inside it add some javascript, example:

```
<button onclick="window.open('mailto:email@email.de');">Kontakt</button>
```

Comment: this opens a new window when i try it using Chrome